# Angular 2 returns error self.context.myFunction using @Output

Tags: javascript, angular, output

I'm getting a problem with the @Output directive. This is my code:

**representatives-list.component.ts**

```
@Output() selected = new EventEmitter();
showRepresentative(event){          
   this.selected.emit(event.data);
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<ar-representatives-list (selected)="onRepresentativeSelected(data)"></ar-representatives-list>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
onRepresentativeSelected(data){
   console.log(data);
}
```

When the `selected`event it's emitted, it returns the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: self.context.onRepresentativeSelected is not a function`

What's happening?

Comment: can you add the `app.component.ts` class to the question?

Comment: Solved! I had a confusion with some archives width the same name and I mixed them... Thanks!

Comment: Also use `onRepresentativeSelected($event)`, to pass the data into the function